# meta name viewport doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, mobile, viewport, meta-tags

I tried all these meta tags on my website but no one of them worked:

```
<meta name="viewport" width="device-width">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

But when I add `@-ms-viewport{ width: device-width; }` to style.css it works, but the width is not 100% on my iPhone and Samsung tab, users still need to scroll horizentally.

My main content width is 1070px.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your page, but i got a similar problem some days ago.
The problem was, that padding-commands made divs bigger than they should have been and this resulted in a horizontal scrolling.

Maybe you could check for your padding elements and maybe remove them (use margin on other elements instead).